# Can Maven know when to install parent pom or tell me when it need it?

Tags: maven

What's the maven way to allow to build individual modules and ensure that changes to parent pom are uploaded into the local repository?

Let's say I have three modules: one parent, two children (dbmod, appmod)

- parent:    dependencyManagement defines jdbc-foo 1.5
- dbmod:   dependencies defines jdbc-foo getting version from parent
- appmod: depens on dbmod

**Situation**

1. I build from parent getting parent-pom with jdbc-foo 1.5, dbmod using jdbc-foo 1.5 and appmod.
2. I update source control and parent pom changes to jdbc-foo 1.6
3. I build in dbmod directory
4. I build in appmod directory

   appmod fetches dbmod from local repository and uses local repo version of parent pom
   maven issues: "[WARNING] The POM for ...dbmod:jar:3.5.0-SNAPSHOT is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for dbmod:3.5.0-SNAPSHOT"

   compilation fails because my code relied on access to jdbc-foo 1.6 changes

**Options**

I can resolve the problem these ways:

- install the parent pom file manually the problem, (mvn install-file ...)
- build from the parent **Unnecessary Building: I build all modules all the time**
- build from the parent selecting the desired project and using also-make (mvn -am -pl :appmod  ...)    **Unnecessary Building: I must build all deps all the time**

First option's a problem because I need to know that I need to do it.  Second and third option also require me to figure out that I need to do it or to build all deps / all mods all the time which can be a problem in a large system.

If there a config setting that would force parent install other than "-am -pl :mod" or is this the "maven way" to handle the situation?

Thanks

Peter

(If maven can't do then then I can right a wrapper script which checks parent against local repo parent and forces install on difference)

Comment: Hmm...Maven SCM plugin (http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/) needs to have post-update hooks. Otherwise, it looks like you'll need a custom Maven plugin / antrun script.

Comment: in step 3 and 4, are you installing the artifact? mvn install? or just compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building from the parent pom is just fine. That is the recommended way together with the reactor options you have mentioned. And if you do NOT run clean it will not duplicate unnecessary effort.

Comment: Actually, the problem is that in the real case I have about 100+ modules.   So, If I build like so:   mvn clean install -pl :modX -am   and there are 45 modules when haven't changed and 4 which have and are scattered in the build order then I'll have a 15-20m build when I really only need a 5m build.

Comment: Then your multi modules build is way to big and should be broken up. In the mean time you can create a custom pom that ties together only the stuff you want rebuilt as modules..

Answer (score -1):

The maven way is to always build from the parent. What exactly is the problem of building all the modules? I am pretty sure maven will not **actually** rebuild the submodules if there are no changes in the code so it is pretty fast. But even if it did, why is this a problem for you?

The other thing to try is to use `<relativePath>` in the parent declaration of the modules. That way maven will get the parent pom from the file system and not from the installed parent artifact

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
  <version>${app.version}</version>
  <relativePath>.../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Comment: Using any sort of relative paths settings are a bad practice and not recommended.

Comment: Can you at least add a reference to support a statement like that? i have never heard that and in some cases it is necessary, otherwise the very first build will fail since the parent hasn't been installed yet

Comment: You have to look at the dev and user mailing list archives. This is one of those well known but not really explicitly written down rules.  In general in Maven everything should be able to build without references outside of the project apart from content retrieved from a repository. So relative and absolute paths are strongly discouraged. If you need to build the parent first you project setup is wrong. Reference I can only add that I am co-author of Maven The Complete Reference and train Maven for Sonatype on a regular basis..

Comment: Ahhh.  I'm solving the wrong problem!  I can't build incrementally on windows due to problems with my antrun executions and fixing that will allow incremental action.  If it's not quick then I can review the actions maven does and make them behave properly in the incremental case